# How to create a an infinite grid using javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript

How to create a zoomable and pannable infinite grid using javascript canvas?

Following is the code for creating a draggable infinite grid using library called snap.js

```
const paper = new Snap("#host");

const minorLineAttr = { stroke: "gray", strokeWidth: 0.5 },
      elements = [],
      dimension = 100,
      divisions = 10;

// background box
elements.push(paper.rect(0, 0, dimension, dimension).attr({
  fill: 'none',
  stroke: "gray", strokeWidth: 1
}));

// add horizontal & vertical lines
const lineCount = dimension / divisions;

for (var index=1; index < lineCount; index++) {
  const offset = lineCount*index,
        sw = minorLineAttr.strokeWidth;
  
  elements.push(paper.line(sw, offset, dimension-sw, offset).attr(minorLineAttr));
  elements.push(paper.line(offset, sw, offset, dimension-sw).attr(minorLineAttr));
}

// construct a 3x3 grid that is essentially masked to a 1x1 pattern
var gridPattern = paper.g(...elements).toPattern(0, 0, dimension, dimension);
const gridRect = paper.rect(-dimension, -dimension, 3*dimension, 3*dimension).attr({fill: gridPattern});
const grid3x3Pattern = gridRect.toPattern(0, 0, dimension, dimension);
const bgRect = paper.rect(0,0,'100%','100%').attr({fill: grid3x3Pattern});

function getElementCoords(x, y, t) {
  return {
    x : t.e + x * t.a + y * t.c,
    y: t.f + x * t.b + y * t.d
  };
}

// transform on drag
const dragStart = function () {
  console.log(this);
  const bbox = this.getBBox(),
        coords = getElementCoords(bbox.x, bbox.y, gridRect.transform().localMatrix);
  this.data("coords", coords);
};

const dragMove = function(dx, dy) {
  const coords = this.data("coords");
  gridRect.transform("t" + (coords.x + dx) % dimension + " " + (coords.y + dy) % dimension);
};

const dragStop = function() {
  this.removeData("coords");
};

bgRect.drag(dragMove, dragStart, dragStop);

paper.text(20, 50, "Drag the background").attr({
  fill: "#fff",
  fontFamily: "Verdana, Arial, Courier",
  fontSize: "24"
});
```

This is working great , but what I want to achieve is that I want to create a similar grid using html5 canvas api..

I'm using Konva for creating html canvas as this library is rich in lot of functionalities.

How can I implement the above infinite zoomable and pannable grid using html5 canvas or using konva js?

**Note** that my canvas is overflowing the screen since the content is a lot.

So we need a way to mimic infinite grid as shown above that clamps to viewport/container/window dimensions and interacts with the user as drags and zooms.

I've tried my own way by creating a bunch of horizontal and vertical lines. But the canvas is getting slow... as I interacts... we need a way to cache or mimic infinite grid so that performance is increased.

But when dragged it is not getting clamped to the viewport/container/window width and height as shown in the above snap.svg example.

How can I achive that?

Comment: I don't use Konva, so am not entirely sure.  You certainly can't render an `infinite` anything.  One thing you could think about is: do you need to render it *all*?  Surely, you only need to render as much as fits on the canvas?  If the user moves outside of the current dimensions you have, add in an extra row or column and redisplay the canvas with just a chunk of the array based on the top-left to bottom-right co-ordinates.

Comment: Probably by first reading up on the principles of rendering an infinite 2d world at several zoom levels, which includes things like "tiling" (only generate the immediately visible content tile and its immediate neighbour) and rendering different things at different zoom levels (which typically requires completely different rendering output for the same object depending on scale). Note that Stackoverflow is not a general help forum though, so if you want to tackle a big topic like this, a graphics forum's programming help section is a far better place to ask this question.

Comment: Can some one show some code?